# Нужно R Studio сохранить обученную модель RF

Tags: машинное-обучение, r

В R Studio я обучила модель RF 
Как я могу сохранить результаты обучения так, чтобы в последствии модель можно было вызвать, передать ей на вход входные параметры и получить прогноз?

Answer (score 2):

Можно сохранить как RDS

```
# сохранить
saveRDS(object, file = "RF.rds")
# загрузить
readRDS(file = "RF.rds")
```